# Обкорінення чи укорінення?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Як правильно укорінення чи обкорінення?

В одному місці читаю:

> …Крім цього, при застосуванні агростеміну зменшується загнивання тканин, завдяки чому збільшується вихід обкорінених живців. Можна припустити, що агростемін посилює поглинання коренями елементів мінерального живлення…
>
> *// (Лісове господарство, лісова, паперова і деревообробна промисловість : міжвідомчий науково-технічний збірник. – Львів: НЛТУ України. – 1986 / 1)
>   «НЛТУ – Нац. лісотех. ун-т України»*

А в іншому:

> УКОРІНИТИ
>
> Значення
>
> 1. посадивши, дати прижитися, закріпитися коренями в ґрунті
> 2. перен. Сприяти широкому поширенню, міцному закріпленню чогось у чомусь; впровадити, міцно встановити
>
> *// [Укоренить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) у російському Вікісловнику*

На мою думку суть проблеми добре розкрито ось тут:

> Обкорінення живців, агротехнічний прийом, що використовується в розсадництві. Полягає в створенні умов, необхідних для утворення коренів на нижньому вузлі виноградних живців. Застосовується для отримання щеплених і кореневласних виноградних саджанців.
>
> Процес обкорінення відбувається наступним чином: в оптимальних умовах зовнішнього середовища зачатки коренів, що закладаються в периферійній зоні серцевинних променів вузла, пробуджують діяльність оточуючих їх тканин, в результаті чого утворюється пухка тканина (звана "кишенькою"). Остання розсовує в сторону флоему.Зачаток корінчика своїм чохликом тисне на рихлу тканину, після чого перидерма розривається і з'являється білий горбочок;корінець прориває його і виходить назовні.
>
> Для прискорення обкорінення живців застосовують кільчування, стратифікацію або регулятори росту.
>
> *// (Литература: Энциклопедия виноградарства: в 3-х томах./Гл. ред. А. И. Тимуш; ред. коллегия А. С. Субботович и др. Кишинев: Гл. ред. Молд. Сов. Энциклопедии, 1986.)*

То все ж, як правильно?
Дякую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коротко:

- Укорінення — дїя дїӥ задля — процес задля
- Обкорінення — дїя дїӥ стати — процес з [передбачувальним] резултатом, як вже і згадали тут.
- Корінення — дїя дїӥ — просто процес, необовязково з резултатом.

Наведу шче приклад:

- *Я укорінював ся в середовишче* — я сам робив спроби бути близьким до середовишча.
- *Я обкорінював ся в середовишчі* — середовишче само зробило мене своӥм без моӥх спроб.

---

Я слово знаьшов ві:

> <sub>[Словник ботанічної термінології](https://archive.org/details/slovnbot/page/n83)</sub>
>
> [**Обкорінювання, обкорінення**](https://archive.org/details/slovnbot/page/n83) — окоренение — *н.* Bewurzelung
>
> **Обкорінюватися, обкоренитися** — окореняться, окорениться — *н.* sich bewarzeln
>
> [**Укорінення**](https://archive.org/details/slovnbot/page/n111) — укоренение — *н.* Einwurzelung

Нїмецьку не знаю, хто знаʼ — уточніть, а я тому́ спершу розбиру ся з приростками:

> <sub>[Синявський](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_pryrostky)</sub>
>
> 15. **о-**, **об-**, **обі**-, **обо-** — хоч в основі це різностаті того самого приростка, та все ж подекуди окремі з них обмежені вживанням не тільки з фонетичних причин (перед голосними, групами приголосних), а й через причини спеціялізації значінь; найчастіше вживається цей приросток і найскладніше його вживання в дієсловах:
>
> а) на означення всебічности, повноти дії: *обки́да́ти, оплакати, обігріти, обсихати*...
>
> Щодо **о-** і **об-** в дієсловах і віддієслівних словах, то до деякої міри вони вживаються як рівнобіжні (рівнозначні), напр., *обсмикати* і *осмикати*, *обдурити* і *одурити*, *обсипатися* і *осипатися*, *обзнайомити* і *ознайомити*..., але взагалі приросток **об-** надає матеріяльнішого, конкретнішого значіння, ніж **о-**, і тому часто дієслова первісного (і звичайно матеріяльного) значіння з **об-** стаються з **о-** дієсловами іншого значіння, звичайно переносного і абстрактнішого, напр.:
>
> > *обвернутися (плащем) — обернутися (вовком)
> >
> >     оббирати (ягоди) — обирати (на голову)
> >
> >     обкинути (болотом) — окинути (оком)
> >
> >     обчищатися (від бруду) — очищатися (регабілітуватися)
> >
> >     обписати (з усіх боків) — описати (подію)
> >
> >     обнова — оновлення
> >
> >     обгидити — огидити, огида
> >
> >     обновити — оповити
> >
> >     обпоганитися — опоганитися
> >
> >     обпаскудити — опаскудити
> >
> >     обзначити — означити* і т. ін.,
>
> а іноді такі дієслова з **о-** зовсім відмінні значінням супроти слів з **об-**, або й взагалі, маючи тільки абстрактніше значіння, вживаються лише з **о-**, напр.:
>
> > *обставляти (чим) — оставляти (= залишати)
> >
> >     обпинатися (хусткою) — опинатися (= не бажати)
> >
> >     обшукувати (= потрусити) — ошукувати (= дурити)
> >
> >     оберігати, одержувати, оповістити, оголосити* тощо.
>
> Звичайно, бувають дієслова й тільки з приростком **об-**, напр.: *обстріляти*, *обкласти* (або *обікласти*) тощо.
>
> б) у дієсловах з іменних пнів на означення "стати чим" тільки **о-**: *овдовіти, осиротіти, остовпіти, одужати, ожити, одубіти, окривіти, опанувати*... (хоч і *обляшитися*), а також у таких, як *оженитися, одружитися, осідлати, остогидіти, окотитися* тощо.
>
> в) в іменниках тощо: *о́бшир, осере́док, обов’язок, о́бмолодь* (іменник), *о́бмаль, о́брідно, о́сторонь* (порівн. **над-**).
>
> ---
>
> 36. **у-** — див. **в-**.
>
> 2. **-в**, **у-** (про міну **в**-**у**-**уві** див. § 15) крім широкого вжитку в дієсловах і інших категоріях слів (*внести, внесок, вмити, вранішній, впоперек*...), приросток **-у**, (**в-**) з прикметникових пнів творить дієслова перехідні з значінням "робити, зробити чим": *унаочнити, узагальнити, ущасливити, унещасливити, усуспільнювати, уворужувати, ударемнити, уміжнароднити*. (Див. іще **з-**, **о-**).

Також варто зазначити, шчо СУМ в 11 книгах має зі згаданим приростком **о-**:

> [Окоренитися](http://sum.in.ua/s/okorenytysja), нюся, нишся, *док., розм., рідко*.
>
> 1. Пустити коріння; укорінитися.
> 2. *перен.* Надовго розташуватися де-небудь або на чомусь. *О, вже сів, окоренився! А не пора додому?* (Словник Грінченка).

Comment: Дуже дякую за чудове першоджерело!

Answer (score 1):

**[Вкорінювати/укорінювати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vkorinjuvaty)** — широковживане слово (зокрема й у варіанті [вкорінюватися/укорінюватися](http://sum.in.ua/s/vkorinjuvatysja)).

**Обкорінювати** я не бачу в жодному словнику. Якщо таке слово в українській мові є, то це, мабуть, якийсь дуже вузький сільськогосподарський термін.

Можу припустити, що *обкорінення* почали казати через те, що *укорінення* почало асоціюватися більше з «воно саме укорінюється», ніж із «ми створюємо спеціальні умови, щоб спровокувати цей процес» (але це лише моє припущення; ніде в Інтернеті я такого слова не бачу).

Comment: Так, це вузькоспеціалізований термін. Стосується лише стеблового, листкового і кореневого живцювання в розмноженні рослин.
Дякую за припущення. Воно також цінне!